# Domain Admin on AWS lacking user rights to edit the top 200 using the Management Studio interface

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, aws

I setup an application + SQL Server on AWS. Everything works fine my SQL User can read/write to any table.

Now I connected to the SQL Server using my domain admin account using windows authentication in SQL Server. It works fine and I can insert / update / delete rows. But as soon as I try to edit a table using the interface, meaning select "Edit Top 200 Rows" I get the following error:

```
The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be 
trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to 
allow delegation.
```

[image: Trusted delegation]

In the local Security Policy I have enabled domain Admins and also my exact account to the following and also all admins:

```
Enable computer and user Accounts to be trusted for delegation
```

[image: Enabled Account]

What else am I missing? I use SQL Server 2014 Standart on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think the Work Around mentioned at [serverfault.com/questions/696804/...](https://serverfault.com/questions/696804/sql-2014-add-table-gives-the-requested-operation-cannot-be-completed-the-comp) is a very valid answer so I am listing it directly here.  I have the exact same issue in Microsoft Azure (editing a table SQL Management Studio).

I fixed it by setting **DWORD** regkey `ProtectionPolicy` to 1 for the sub-key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb`